# How can I know the client is in the same network of the server on an asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking

There is a web server and a website on it.
It's internal IP is **192.168.2.10**
It's external ip is **77.xxx.xxx.xxx**

**Client A:** This one is in the same network of the server,and it's local ip is  **192.168.2.11**
**Client B:**This one is outside of the network,and its external ip is **195.xxx.xxx.xxx**

**Client A** and **Client B** are both can connect the website.**Client A** connects the website through internal ip of server.Client B connects the website through external ip of the server.

How can I know the client is in local area or outside?

Answer (score 1):

Do this, get the IP address like this:

```
String ipAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Then do a check like this

```
if (ipAddress == "192.168.2.11")
{
//user is within network
}
else
{
//user is external
}
```

Just alter the above code to do a check for anyone in the 192.168.2.xxx range if need be.

Comment: ip address' are sample and they are dynamic. The main problem is how can I know the client is inside or outside? Ip address'  can be different and many clients can be inside and the outside

Comment: Ah thats simple, just get the server IP, do the comparison then you will still find out if its local or not.  So to recap instead of hard coding the "192.168.2.11" instead replace that with the server IP range.

eg:  you get server IP of 192.168.1.1, substring on the 3rd fullstop so you end up with just 192.168.1  - then do the same with client IP and compare the 2.

Comment: Client B can be have the same local ip range although it was outside of the network

Comment: Ok now I understand, try this...get the local IP of the server, then client ip using:

protected void GetUser_IP()
{
    string VisitorsIPAddr = string.Empty;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
    {
        VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
    }
    else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
    {
        VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    //VisitorsIPAddr;
}

then compare server local IP vs visitor IP range

Comment: The above code will give you the public IP of the client given by your service provider if they go via the 'outside' route...if a public IP is given that isnt on the same range as server local IP then its outside the network, else its being executed internally.